# JSON get key path in nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
json = '{
    "app": {
        "Garden": {
            "Flowers": {
                "Red flower": "Rose",
                "White Flower": "Jasmine",
                "Yellow Flower": "Marigold"
            }
        },
        "Fruits": {
            "Yellow fruit": "Mango",
            "Green fruit": "Guava",
            "White Flower": "groovy"
        },
        "Trees": {
            "label": {
                "Yellow fruit": "Pumpkin",
                "White Flower": "Bogan"
            }
        }
    }'
```

Here is my json string, which keeps on changing frquently so the keys position within the dictionary is not same everytime, i need to
search for a key and print it corresponding value, Since the json string changes everytime I have written an recursive function(See below) to search
for key in the new json string and print the value. However now the situation is we have same key multiple times with diff values, how can
i get the complete path of the key so it would be easier to understand which key value it is, for example the result should be like this:

```
app.Garden.Flowers.white Flower = Jasmine
app.Fruits.White Flower = groovy
app.Trees.label.White Flower = Bogan
```

**My code so far:**

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
  j = json.load(data_file)


def find(element, JSON):    
  if element in JSON:
    print JSON[element].encode('utf-8')
  for key in JSON:
    if isinstance(JSON[key], dict):
      find(element, JSON[key])
 


find(element to search,j)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a string parameter that keeps track of the current JSON path.  Something like the following could work:

```
def find(element, JSON, path, all_paths):    
  if element in JSON:
    path = path + element + ' = ' + JSON[element].encode('utf-8')
    print path
    all_paths.append(path)
  for key in JSON:
    if isinstance(JSON[key], dict):
      find(element, JSON[key],path + key + '.',all_paths)
```

You would call it like this:

```
all_paths = []
find(element_to_search,j,'',all_paths)
```

Comment: Thanks...however it's a recursive function and it's returning None at the end..can we fix it?

Comment: Returning multiple things from a function like this would be tricky.  An easier way is to have a list that you pass in, like I have added in this edited version, that collects all the final paths.  After the function is called, `all_paths` will have all the data that is printed.

Comment: line 7, in find
    path = path + element + ' = ' + JSON[element].encode('utf8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That's a separate issue.  If you can't figure out what's going wrong, make a separate question with all the information that you know.

Comment: Hope i shld be able to fix this issue on my own...thanks for all ur help so far..cheers..

Comment: posted this question separately, not able to debug why this issue is cropping up bcoz of special character in the value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011731/ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3-in-position-3

Answer (score 0):

```
def getDictValueFromPath(listKeys, jsonData):
    """
    >>> mydict = {
        'a': {
            'b': {
                'c': '1'
            }
        }
    }
    >>> mykeys = ['a', 'b']
    >>> getDictValueFromPath(mykeys, mydict)
    {'c': '1'}
    """
    localData = jsonData.copy()
    for k in listKeys:
        try:
            localData = localData[k]
        except:
            return None
return localData
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/nitrocode/d1fdc012994a75b865e043523f8f2eb7)

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will give a list of paths that are accessible in the JSON. It's following the convention of JSON paths where `[]` signifies that the path is a list.

```py
def get_paths(source):
    paths = []
    if isinstance(source, collections.abc.MutableMapping):
        for k, v in source.items():
            if k not in paths:
                paths.append(k)
            for x in get_paths(v):
                if k + '.' + x not in paths:
                    paths.append(k + '.' + x)
    elif isinstance(source, collections.abc.Sequence) and not isinstance(source, str):
        for x in source:
            for y in get_paths(x):
                if '[].' + y not in paths:
                    paths.append('[].' + y)
    return paths
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a modified version of Brian's answer that supports lists and returns the result:

```
def find(element, JSON, path='', all_paths=None):
    all_paths = [] if all_paths is None else all_paths
    if isinstance(JSON, dict):
        for key, value in JSON.items():
            find(element, value, '{}["{}"]'.format(path, key), all_paths)
    elif isinstance(JSON, list):
        for index, value in enumerate(JSON):
            find(element, value, '{}[{}]'.format(path, index), all_paths)
    else:
        if JSON == element:
            all_paths.append(path)
    return all_paths
```

Usage:

```
find(JSON, element)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me