# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3

Tags: python, json

Not sure why this error is coming up because of a special character in the value, I'm trying to get the value of a key from the json using this recursive function provided by @Brien.

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010299/json-get-key-path-in-nested-dictionary`

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
  j = json.load(data_file)

def find(element, JSON,path,all_paths):
  if element in JSON:
    path = path + element + ' = ' + JSON[element].encode('utf-8')
    print path
    all_paths.append(path)
  for key in JSON:
    if isinstance(JSON[key], dict):      
      find(element, JSON[key],path + key + '.',all_paths)   


all_paths = []
find('userNameField',j,'',all_paths)
print all_paths
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things wrong about your code:

1. When you call on an item from JSON you should assign to variable then encode or encode as it's being loaded.
2. When you encode a string, which is what `json.load` type is,  you're changing it to byte. Adding `str` + `byte` after you properly encode the variable will rise another error.

Try the following:

```
j = json.load(data_file, encoding='utf-8')
#....
path = path + element + ' = ' + str(JSON[element])
```

Comment: Can you check the type for `JSON[element]`?

Answer (score -2):

Usually such errors occur when somebody tries to encode a string that was not decoded. I would suggest `JSON[element].decode('utf-8')`. You can encode it later if you need to.