# Find all paths to all values in a JSON document

Tags: c++, json, algorithm

For each value in a JSON document, I want a sequence of keys that leads to that value. In other words, I am looking for a way to return a vector containing all of the paths to each value in a JSON document. The result (sequence of paths) should be a vector, and a path should be a vector of JSON keys, a key should be a string.

So the final result should be stored in a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> allPaths`.

The solution can use any JSON parsing library, it doesn't matter what dependencies the solution uses (obviously, fewer dependencies and readable code are preferred).

Example JSON document:

```
{
  "shopper": {
    "Id": "4973860941232342",
    "Context": {
      "CollapseOrderItems": false,
      "IsTest": false
    }
  },
  "SelfIdentifiersData": {
    "SelfIdentifierData": [
      {
        "SelfIdentifierType": {
          "SelfIdentifierType": "111"
        }
      },
      {
        "SelfIdentifierType": {
          "SelfIdentifierType": "2222"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Result for the example JSON document:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> allPaths;                     // container to store the result

allPaths.push_back({"shopper"});                                    // path to an object
allPaths.push_back({"shopper", "Id"});                              // path to string "4973860941232342"
allPaths.push_back({"shopper", "Context"});                         // path to an object
allPaths.push_back({"shopper", "Context", "CollapseOrderItems"});   // path to boolean false
allPaths.push_back({"shopper", "Context", "IsTest"});               // path to boolean false

allPaths.push_back({"SelfIdentifiersData"});                        // path to an object
allPaths.push_back({"SelfIdentifiersData", "SelfIdentifierData"});  // path to an array
```

Note that we don't need to return paths to elements of an array. So we don't have something like:

```
// we don't need paths to individual elements of an array, a path to the entire array is enough
allPaths.push_back({"SelfIdentifiersData", "SelfIdentifierData", "array_index: 0"});  
allPaths.push_back({"SelfIdentifiersData", "SelfIdentifierData", "array_index: 1"});
```

So far I tried using [RapidJson](https://rapidjson.org/) to parse the plain-text json document, and then to use a depth-first search (recursion+backtracking) to find all paths:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "rapidjson-master/include/rapidjson/document.h"  // single header include for the json parsing library: https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson#installation

using namespace rapidjson;

// rapidJson uses this to determine the type of the value for a key-value pair
static const char* kTypeNames[] =
        { "Null", "False", "True", "Object", "Array", "String", "Number" };

void dfs(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &result, std::vector<std::string> &currPath, const Value &currElement) {

    // add current path to result (create separate copy to avoid modifications of paths that have been added to the result)
    std::vector<std::string> newQuery(currPath);
    result.push_back(newQuery);


    // if current key doesn't have an object (document) as value then we can't go down further so simply return (end current recursive call)
    if (currElement.GetType() != 3) {
        return;
    }


    // iterate all key-value pairs reachable from currPath, for each make one recursive call (add currKey to currPath, modify parsedJsonObj (move down a level at currKey), recurse, backtrack by removing currKey from currPath and by moving back parsedJsonObj)
    for (Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = currElement.MemberBegin(); itr != currElement.MemberEnd(); ++itr) {
        //printf("Type of member %s is %s\n", itr->name.GetString(), kTypeNames[itr->value.GetType()]);

        currPath.push_back(itr->name.GetString());

        dfs(result, currPath, itr->value);

        currPath.pop_back();
    }

}

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> generateAllQueries(std::string &plainTextJson) {

    Document document;
    document.Parse(plainTextJson.c_str());

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> result;
    std::vector<std::string> currPath;
    dfs(result, currPath, document);

    return result;
}
```

There are [similar questions out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010299/json-get-key-path-in-nested-dictionary) but they use different languages and don't return paths to objects (subdocuments).

I'm currently stuck at finishing this, I'm not sure how to make the recurisve calls correctly. Solutions without rapidjson and a completely different approach are totally fine. Only constraint is that it must be in C++.

Comment: Your approach seems good. So you want us to fill your todos? I don't see any question. Just traverse all leafs, store the the path to the leaf if value is equal. Done.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta SO questions are not meant to ask people here to solve the problem for you. The purpose is to ask for help with a specific problem that you have encountered in your tries. It looks to me that you have the start of the solution (or 90% of it basically), then you've just stopped half-way and now your asking someone else to finish what you started. This is really nothing more then the recursive equivalent of some for loops with `if`s.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta I'm unfortunately not 10 years old. Trying to trick me into doing your homework is gonna require a bit more brains then that.

Comment: @super I'm not trying to trick anyone into anything. This is a problem I currently face and I'm asking for help as I struggle with it and think it's not trivial.

Comment: You can look at it this way. Your JSON data is an array. Every element of the array is either another array or a value. No matter which one of the two you encounter, you add it's path to the result. If the added value was an array, recursively call the function on all the elements of that array.

Comment: Hint: you probably want `rapidjson::Value &` not `rapidjson::Document &` as the parameter to `dfs`

Comment: @Caleth How to check whether a rapidjson::Value is an object (subdocument)?

Comment: Have a look at https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#QueryObject

Comment: @Caleth Thank you. How would you make the recurisve call that adds all the paths to values in a subdocument? If I do `dfs(result, currPath, itr->value);` I get problems because of the `rapidjson::Value` type (see updated the code the question)

Comment: Ah, `const Value &`. You are using a const iterator

Comment: @Caleth Nice. What do you think about the current solution (see updated question)? Do you see any issues? Would you change anything about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203327/discussion-between-caleth-and-anna-vopureta).